# How I can set the result of the query vertical?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need the result of the query to be presented veritical, currently it is presented like this

```
select top (1) *  from [dbo].[TBL_Pega_PSI_COMMENTS]

ID  strConditionDocNo   strReasonID strComments
1   C0SC3901900492  5   Case
```

I need like this

```
1
C0SC3901900492  
5
Case
```

Im using SQL Server, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as (
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM [dbo].[TBL_Pega_PSI_COMMENTS]
)
SELECT field_value
from cte
unpivot
(
field_value
  for field_name in (ID,strConditionDocNo, strReasonID, strComments)
) unpiv;
```